# Google maps autocomplete with angular materials

Tags: angular, google-maps-api-3, angular-material

I am trying to use the google maps autocomplete in an angular materials form when a user enters a location. It does not seem to be reading the input correctly because I get this error:[image]

Here's my code

**html:**

```
<mat-form-field>
             <input matInput placeholder="Event Location" [formControl]="eventLocation" required #search type="text" id= "place">
</mat-form-field>
```

**ts:**

```
firstFormGroup: FormGroup;
public eventLocation: FormControl;
public searchElementRef: ElementRef;
eventPost: Latlong;
eventLat: number;
eventLng: number;
@ViewChild('search')

ngOnInit() {

      this.firstFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
        eventName: ['', Validators.required],
        eventLocation: ['', Validators.required]
      });
      this.eventLocation = new FormControl;
      this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
        const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
          this.searchElementRef.nativeElement, {
            types: []
        });
          autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', () => {
            this.ngZone.run(() => {
              const place: google.maps.places.PlaceResult = autocomplete.getPlace();
              if (place.geometry === undefined || place.geometry === null) {
                return;
              }
              this.eventPost = {
                latitude: place.geometry.location.lat(),
                longitude: place.geometry.location.lng()
              };
              this.mydata.latlongSource.next({ ...this.eventPost });
              this.eventLat = this.eventPost.latitude;
              this.mydata.markerLatSource.next( this.eventLat);
              this.eventLng = this.eventPost.longitude;
              this.mydata.markerLngSource.next( this.eventLng);
              this.eventLocation.reset();
            });
          });
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nativeElement` is a DOM element. You don't yet have the DOM in `OnInit` hook. Use `AfterViewInit` to access DOM elements:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {

      this.firstFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
        eventName: ['', Validators.required],
        eventLocation: ['', Validators.required]
      });
```

Comment: from your code i see you just define `searchElementRef`, but dont set any value to it - `public searchElementRef: ElementRef;`. So i assume you instead of `public searchElementRef: ElementRef;` **and** `@ViewChild('search')` want `@ViewChild('search') searchElementRef: ElementRef`